Can I configure MemoryCache to keep the n most recent items?
I would like to cache the n most recent items using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory. Once the cache size hits n, the oldest item should be evicted to make room for the newest.
I can set the size limit like so:
use memoryCache = new MemoryCache(MemoryCacheOptions(SizeLimit = 10_000L))

But I'm not sure how to configure the eviction.
Can this be done? If so, how?

check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-8.0 section MemoryCacheEntryOptions (on any update/insert - evict)
